# Pulsar 220Fi starter crackling sound

Tags: fuel-system, starter, fuel-injection, pulsar

So I've a Plusar 220Fi 2007 model. Engine is in perfect as new condition. However sometimes when I press the start button, I huge crackling sounds can be heard (it's like metal balls are ground together) and I had to release the button. But after few tries, the bike starts like a charm with not a single noise and then few more self starts doesn't give any problem. Been wondering what issue is it so that I could fix it or could estimate the cost to fix it. It would be more helpful if you guys had the same issue and share your experience.

I've read on forums that it is an issue with the starter relay which is square in shape beside the battery and needs to be replaced with a dome shape relay but the relay is already dome in shape.

Also, for more information, just installed a new battery which originally 220 supports (12V 9Amp). Gear shifting has issues (mostly had to ride on a 1st or 2nd gear, the gears don't shift most of the time, mechanic said it's clutch plate issues, but I don't think so as once gear is shifted, the clutch and gear works fine, also pickup is fabulous).

Thank you.